# SQL server is very slow when retrieving data with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Retrieving data from my SQL Server is very slow. Does any one see a problem?

Create the SQL Server table:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("jaar", jaartal);
    cmd.CommandText =
        @" 

       BEGIN
       CREATE TABLE " + jaartal + @"(
        [code] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [type] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [datum] [datetime] NULL,
        [uur] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [controller] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [fout] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [teller] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [omschrijving] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [graad] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var1] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var2] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var3] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var4] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var5] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var6] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var7] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var8] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var9] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var10] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var11] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var12] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var13] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var14] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var15] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var16] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var17] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var18] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var19] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var20] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var21] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var22] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var23] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var24] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var25] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var26] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var27] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var28] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var29] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var30] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var31] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var32] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var33] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var34] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var35] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var36] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var37] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var38] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var39] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [var40] [Varchar](max) NULL,
        [Cat_MMAP] [Varchar](max) NULL
        ); END";

    try
    {           
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    { 
    }
}

connection.Close();
```

Retrieving data from SQL Server:

I have a table for every year so I must look in all these tables.

But I have 1000 000 rows in all the database.

```
Tbl_events.Columns.Clear();

aantalfouten = 0; //numbers of error 
jaartaltabel = DataContainer.jaartalstart;
statusbalk.Value=statusbalk.Minimum;

while (aantalfouten < 40)
{
    try
    {
        statusbalk.Visible = true;

        tabelnaam = "Evenementen" + jaartaltabel.ToString(); //create name of the table that i want to read so as Events2013                       
        connection.Open(); 
        datatabel.Load(new SqlCommand("SELECT type,datum,uur,controller,fout,teller,omschrijving,graad,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20,var21,var22,var23,var24,var25,var26,var27,var28,var29,var30,var31,var32,var33,var34,var35,Cat_MMAP  FROM " + tabelnaam + " where " + filter + "", connection).ExecuteReader());//Select statement
        connection.Close();

        Tbl_events.DataSource = datatabel.DefaultView; //insert the data in my datagridview this takes also a  lot of time
        jaartaltabel++;
    }
    catch
    {
        jaartaltabel++;
        aantalfouten++;
        connection.Close();
    }
}
ColumnWidth();
```

I have also use a filter with the where statement for don't receive all the data.

Sometimes I have also a system out of memory exception.

Does anyone have a solution for these problems?

Comment: You're doing it wrong.

Comment: What do i wrong then? I increment aantalfouten in the catch exception. When the tabelname doesn't excist he will go to the catch. This will gives an error and i will increment the number of errors

Comment: There are a number of possibilities here. The first thing I would do is try to identify if the slowness occurs on the sql or C# side. Can you run your query directly on the database (i.e. not via C#) and see how long it takes and also what the actual execution plan produces ?

Comment: If you're seeing slowness in retrieving data, I'd suggest trying to apply an index to the tables first (when you create them).  Also consider using a stored procedure for retrieving the data.

Comment: This is surely not a good idea. 
I suggest to redo the whole code, because it's no wonder that it takes ages to get data out of the db if you try 40+ times to access a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: why does it loop until there have been 40 errors? is there no *other* exit condition? i.e. some kind of ***success***? Loading 1M rows takes some bandwidth / time - should be in the seconds. I expect that *loop* is the main problem, though

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih actually, trying (and failing) to access a table that doesn't exist will be really fast - even when done 40 times. Not a great idea, but that won't take any appreciable time. My concern is: why does it not exit when it **can** access the table

Comment: Why do you open and close the connection inside the loop?

Comment: Some things that you are doing wrong: Unless you really know what you are doing, you should _not_ have a table for each year, you should _not_ create tables dynamically, and you should _not_ have 40 varchar columns named var1...var40. You need to redesign your entire database. Really.

Comment: for your sake use `SqlParameter` and use `stored procedure` for creating table and retrieving data. Also create index on table

Comment: The loop is not the problem that works very good. I have add indexes to my tabel with my sql management tool and retrieving data is also slow

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, you're right. I meant that it takes _more_ time than it could take. I suggest that he loads the needed tables into a `List<String>`, goes through the list and executes the SQLStatements inside a `Thread` if they're the problem.

Comment: i need the 40 varchar collums because i have 40 variables that i want to save

Comment: Does anyone have solution how i can use a stored procedure on this code?

Comment: [Read this excellent article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) and **stop over-using** `VARCHAR(MAX)` for every column! Use it **only** when really, **truly** needed.....

Comment: What must i use then for a collumn with text in it?

Comment: @user2282583 a stored procedure would make no difference here at all. There are two main problems here: the infinite loop, and the amount of data you want to fetch in one go. A stored procedure addresses **neither of these**. Seriously: people have told you about 5 times that you have an obvious infinite loop: ***fix that***.

Comment: @user2282583 re the "40 variables to save" - simply: name them properly. If one of them is "model size", ***call that column `ModelSize`***. If another is "originator", ***call that column `Originator`***.

Answer (score 3):

You are running the query till you have 40 faults, this means you continue running your query till you have 40 exception. The exceptions will come when you run out of memory... This means you will retrieve a lot of data before crashing, and that will take a while.

Remove the while and you will be fine.

Or do you want to get 40 jaartabellen? Change aantalfouten to jaartaltabel:

```
 while (aantalfouten < 40) ====> while (jaartaltabel < 40)
```

I think your filter is on the `[datum] [datetime] NULL` column of the tables, so add a index on the datum column will improve you query if you have a lot of data in your table (at the end you your create table queries).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_"+jaartal+" ON "+jaartal+" 
(
     datum
) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW
```

Comment: The loop with aantalfouten is not the problem . the problem is that retrieving the data from the SQL server is to slow

Comment: You have a nearly endless loop (how many jaartaltabel do  you have?). The problem is not in you sql, but in your CODE. Abeit your sql can be better: column names, indexes, sql injection, parameterized queries, etc.

Comment: But i can only ad en index on datum

Answer (score 1):

in while loop if everythg is ok use break; to comeout of the loop

```
 while (aantalfouten < 40)
{
   try
   {
       statusbalk.Visible = true;

       tabelnaam = "Evenementen" + jaartaltabel.ToString(); //create name of the table that i want to read so as Events2013                       
       connection.Open(); 
       SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT type,datum,uur,controller,fout,teller,omschrijving,graad,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20,var21,var22,var23,var24,var25,var26,var27,var28,var29,var30,var31,var32,var33,var34,var35,Cat_MMAP  FROM " + tabelnaam + " where " + filter + "", connection);//Select statement
       SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       adp.Fill(ds);

       connection.Close();

       Tbl_events.DataSource = ds; //insert the data in my datagridview this takes also a  lot of time
       jaartaltabel++;
       break;
   }
   catch
   {
      jaartaltabel++;
      aantalfouten++;
      connection.Close();
   }
  }
```

Comment: The while loop is not the problem. The problem is that recieving the data with the databel.load instruction needs to much time