# Place datatable in datagridview is to slow

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to place the data of my datatable in my datagridview with this code.

```
   Tbl_events.DataSource = datatabel.DefaultView;
```

This take a lot of time. 
Is there a faster solution for it

full code

```
                            connection.Open();
                            //datatabel.Load(new SqlCommand("SELECT type,datum,uur,controller,fout,teller,omschrijving,graad,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20,var21,var22,var23,var24,var25,var26,var27,var28,var29,var30,var31,var32,var33,var34,var35,Cat_MMAP  FROM " + tabelnaam + " where " + filter + "", connection).ExecuteReader());

Tbl_events.DataSource=(new SqlCommand("SELECT type,datum,uur,controller,fout,teller,omschrijving,graad,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20,var21,var22,var23,var24,var25,var26,var27,var28,var29,var30,var31,var32,var33,var34,var35,Cat_MMAP  FROM " + tabelnaam + " where " + filter + "", connection).ExecuteReader());

                            connection.Close();


                            jaartaltabel++;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            jaartaltabel++;
                            aantalfouten++;

                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    //Tbl_events.DataSource = datatabel.DefaultView;
                 // ColumnWidth();
                    statusbalk.Increment(20);
                }
                rijsql = 0;
```

i have try to put the data from the sql in datagridview.datasource but this doesn't work.
Its not the sql query that takes a lot of time but this code :Tbl_events.DataSource = datatabel.DefaultView;

Comment: Kinda hard to answer this a little more info than this would be helpful...

Comment: Is the assignment slow or the SQL-Query? The code you showed us, doesn't really help at all.

Comment: In your previous question, the data volume you mention was 1M rows and 50 columns. In which case the answer is simply: don't data-bind a `DataTable` with 1M rows and 50 columns (what is the user going to do with that, really?). So: how many rows / columns *do* you have?

Comment: The only thing i want to do is display the data

Comment: @user2282583 so again: how much data is there?

Comment: Isn't that the same question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807998/sql-server-is-very-slow-when-retrieving-data-with-c-sharp

Comment: at this moment there are 3500 lines in the table. But when all the data is uploaded there is like in my previous question 1M row and 50 columns. But recieving the data from the sql server don't to take all the time but it is to place the data from the datatable in a datagridview that takes a lot of time.

Comment: no that's not the same question. there i want to optimize my sql table. That have i done now; I have change te varchar (max) to varchar(50), i hope that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well their can a lot of reasons for this

1. The data set may be very heavy
2. The query might be taking very long time
   and many more

you should check if the query is taking long time to execute or not by using sql profiler and if its not the reason then look for the no of rows it is returning.